# Кавычки при внутренней речи, оканчивающейся вопросом

Tags: прямая-речь, кавычки

У Розенталя: "Независимо от места, занимаемого по отношению к авторским словам, кавычками выделяется, КАК ПРАВИЛО, внутренняя речь, невысказанные мысли: Смотрю вслед ему и думаю:«Зачем живут такие люди?» 
У него же в БСП пример: Я ехала, говорила с вами и все думала: почему они не стреляют?

Почему в первом случае есть кавычки, а во втором нет?
Что значит "как правило"? Следует ли понимать, что автор сам решает, ставить ли кавычки или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это тема различного оформления дословных высказываний в виде предложения с прямой речью, а также другими способами (косвенная речь, БСП, член предложения, вводные слова).

**Кавычки** ставятся при классическом оформлении **прямой речи** и не ставятся в  **бессоюзном сложном предложении** (БСП) с изъяснительным значением.

1) ***Смотрю вслед ему и думаю: «Зачем живут такие люди?"***

Это **конкретный мысленный речевой акт**, отнесенный к  определенному моменту времени. В  предложении выделяется прямая речь и слова автора. Кавычки по правилам ставятся.

Такое оформление характерно для глаголов  "говорить, думать, сказать", поэтому Розенталь говорит "как правило".

2) ***Я ехала, говорила с вами и все думала: почему они не стреляют?***

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП), кавычки не ставятся.

Здесь ситуация **особая**: обозначено  **не конкретно сформулированная мысль**, а  скорее **тема для размышлений**.

Обратим внимание на выражение "всё думала", а также на параллельность действий (разговаривала и при этом думала). В действительности мысли могли иметь другую форму, например: "Они должны бы сейчас стрелять, но они не делают это? Интересно, почему?"

Таким образом, **смысловая разница есть**, и мы можем обозначить это  с помощью разного оформления предложений.

С другой стороны, **авторский выбор всегда присутствует.** Ведь можно и первое предложение рассматривать как указание **на тему для размышления**, поэтому в каждом случае учитывается ряд факторов.

Сравним **три варианта оформления** (СПП, БСП, прямая речь):

*Смотрю вслед ему и думаю, зачем живут такие люди?*

*Смотрю вслед ему и думаю: зачем живут такие люди?*

*Смотрю вслед ему и думаю: "Зачем живут такие люди?"*

Первый вариант лучше смотрится в таком виде: *Я посмотрел ему вслед и подумал, зачем вообще живут такие люди.*

Второй и третий варианты различаются **паузой,** выделительная способность наибольшая у варианта с прямой речью.

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае буквально процитирован возникший вопрос. Во втором же примере выражение "*всё думаю*" исключает возможность самоцитирования, поскольку  этим выражением обозначена *тема* размышлений, которые повторялись в разных вариациях (по одной или по другой причине не стреляют и т. п.). Здесь даже возможна запятая вместо двоеточия, с точкой вместо вопросительного знака.